# PHP Form Submit Button Unclickable

Tags: php, forms

**SOLVED - permissions**
I want to walk through my debug process so that it might help anyone else working through the same thing... 1) I wiped both pages and replaced with the code that I knew worked. 2) I then changed the form piece by piece until I got it how i wanted and continued testing 3) I then copied the current php file completely and redirected my form to it. 4) it failed... I changed the permissions to 655 and wallah it worked. Now I can go about hacking about the PHP code to get what I want. thanks for all of the suggestions, you definitely led me down the road to my solution
**SOLVED**

I have two separate intake forms on a site.  Intake form 1 works perfectly.  I takes, name, email and comment and sends it through a sendmail script.

I also wanted an intake form for lead capture to track those that want to access the demo videos so I modified the code from the form (for the new page) and then created an additional php file called videoform.php - which is basically just a modified version of my sendmail.php file.

When I fill out the form it does nothing when I click on submit.  It validates, as it not let you enter a null value in any of the fields but I am not sure what I am missing.  Is it something simple (I am by no means PHP reliable) or can I simply not do that?

Here is the form and the php:

```
<div class="message"></div>
            <form action="./php/videoform.php" method="POST" id="contact-form">
                <p class="column one-half">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                </p>

                <p class="column one-half">
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                </p>

                 <p class="column one-half">
                    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Your Phone" required>
                </p>



                <p>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </p>            
            </form>
        </div>
```

This is the PHP

```
    <?php if(!$_POST) exit;
    $to         = "xxxxx@example.com";
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $content    = $_POST['content'];

    $subject    = "You've been contacted by $name";

    $content    = "$name filled out a request to view the online videos:\r\n\n";
    $content   .= "Phone: $phone \n\nEmail: $email \n\n";

    if ($success) {
       header("Location: /videos.html");
       exit;
    } else {
       header("Location: /video-form.html");
       exit;
    }
    ?>
```

I am comfortable with a number of coding formats but I am so weak when it comes to PHP.  Any insight would be both appreciated and get me on the road to understanding PHP better.

Working scripts for comparison

Form

#### Send us a message

```
                <p class="column one-half last">
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                </p>

                <p class="clear">
                    <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Your Message" cols="5" rows="3" required></textarea>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Comment">
                </p>            
            </form>
        </div>
```

PHP sendmail.php file

```
<?php if(!$_POST) exit;
$to         = "xxxxx@example.com";
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$comment    = $_POST['comment'];

$subject    = "You've been contacted by $name";

$content    = "$name sent you a message from your enquiry form:\r\n\n";
$content   .= "Contact Reason: $comment \n\nEmail: $email \n\n";

if(@mail($to, $subject, $content, "Reply-To: $email \r\n")) {
    echo "<h5 class='success'>Message Sent</h5>";
    echo "<br/><p class='success'>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted and someone will contact you shortly.</p>";
}else{
    echo "<h5 class='failure'>Sorry, Try again Later.</h5>";
}?>
```

Answer (score 3):

From your php:

```
//...
$content    = "$name filled out a request to view the online videos:\r\n\n";
$content   .= "Phone: $phone \n\nEmail: $email \n\n";

if ($success) {
    header("Location: /videos.html");
    exit;
} else {
//...
```

You never define $success. Since it doesn't have a value, `if ($success)` fails, and it always enters the `else` portion of the statement. It looks like you're missing a line that's something like `$success = mail($to, $subject, $content);`

Comment: @DiMono - i am going to go ahead and delete that section

Comment: I took that out and it still won't submit.   Maybe i will add that section back in and add the line you suggested.

Comment: @DiMono - added that back in with the line you suggested and I am still getting a non-submit response.  Dang, not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What happens if you just add `$success = true;` instead?

Comment: @DiMono - good suggestion, tried it.  Form still won't submit though.

Comment: Then you need to add some `echo`s to your code so you can see the state of your variables as your progress. That will help to inform your troubleshooting, because you'll actually be able to compare what *should be* true with what *is* true. We've gone as far as we can with the information provided.

Comment: @DiMono - yeah, that's kind of what I was trying to get across here, it won't even get that far.  Echo in the first line does nothing.  Guess I will have to pay someone to debug this for me as I have spent enough company money on it for today.

Comment: SOLVED - want to walk through my debug process so that it might help anyone else working through the same thing...

1) I wiped both pages and replaced with the code that I knew worked.
2) I then changed the form piece by piece until I got it how i wanted and continued testing
3) I then copied the current php file completely and redirected my form to it.
4) it failed... I changed the permissions to 655 and wallah it worked.  Now I can go about hacking about the PHP code to get what I want.  thanks for all of the suggestions, you definitely led me down the road to my solution.